# Parameters.xml - what is the best way to include many of them?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015, msdeploy, msbuild-wpp

We have a couple of environments where we want to deploy our webapp to. We would like to include a range of `setparameters.xml` files in our project and when we execute the web publishing pipeline (wpp) we want those be copied over to the destionation folder. What would be the additions we need to include in `wpp.targets`?

We are using Visual Studio 2013 / 2015.

Comment: a couple of environments? Did you mean you want to deploy to several servers?

Answer (score 0):

No changes are required in the wpp.targets file.  We have 4-7 different SetParameters.[env].xml files for most of our products.  We keep this in the root of the web application project.

We use the -setParamFile flag to set the necessary parameter file for the right environment when we execute the *.deploy.cmd file.  We use Thoughtworks GO! to trigger the deployment but you can use any release orchestration product or just the commandline.